# backdrop overlap my modal form using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem in my modal form. When I clicked the login, my form will show but the backdrop overlap. Here's my JS before:

```
$('#user-login').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#s-auth-login').modal({
            'backdrop': false, //if true the backdrop will overlap
            'show': true
        });
    });
```

I forced the backdrop to hide. But is there any alternative way to do this? I want to retain the background with an opacity color behind my form modal.

Comment: do u have it in jsfiddle? to test?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply show the bootstrap modal without any additional configurations like

```
 $('#s-auth-login').modal('show');
```

This should handle all the things by default.